# I know there has to be a faster way to solve this or the exam wouldn't have it. Can somone please help.

Tags: probability

If you draw 4 M&M's from a bag containing 4 red, 4 yellow, 4 green and 4 brown ones, what is the probability that you will get one of each color?

A. 48/455

B. 64/455

C. 128/1,365

D. 24/256

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: Faster than what?

Comment: I thought it be something like {1/15} x {1/14} x {1/13}

Comment: How in the world did you come up with that?

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is B  which is  $$64/455$$

Note that the probabilities are conditional and they are $$ 16/16, 12/15, 8/14, 4/13$$When multiplied we get $$ 384/2730 =64/455$$